# Ansible: Можно ли назначить роль из командной строки?

Tags: ansible

> Внимание! Этот вопрос является переводом вопроса: [Ansible: Can i
>   execute role from command
>   line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38350674/5752652)

Предположим, у меня есть роль с названием `apache`

Я хочу в командной строке назначить эту роль серверу 192.168.0.10 командой наподобие такой:

```
ansible-playbook -i  "192.168.0.10" --role  "path to role"
```

Есть ли какой-то способ для этого?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Константин, не хотите присоединиться к переводу? Перевести свой ответ с en-so? ) С вас перевод своего ответа (и два других тоже можно вписать), с меня -- галка.

Comment: Думаете, это сработает? Позвать-то можно не кого угодно: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2576/181100

Comment: @D-side Да, я в курсе как работает механизм оповещений, но я не звал его, а просто оставил уведомление, потому что знаю, что Константин читает метки ansible на en-so и ru-so ежедневно. Там переводить три строки, остальное код, но подожду день-другой прежде чем самому переводить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод моего [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419466/2795592) со SO:

Пока в Ansible такой возможности нет (по крайней мере вплоть до версии 2.3), но можно написать небольшой bash-скрипт и положить его в директорию с исполняемыми файлами, например `/usr/local/bin/ansible-role`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# < 2 ]]; then
  cat <<HELP
Wrapper script for ansible-playbook to apply single role.

Usage: $0 <host-pattern> <role-name> [ansible-playbook options]

Examples:
  $0 dest_host my_role
  $0 custom_host my_role -i 'custom_host,' -vv --check
HELP
  exit
fi

HOST_PATTERN=$1
shift
ROLE=$1
shift

echo "Trying to apply role \"$ROLE\" to host/group \"$HOST_PATTERN\"..."

export ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH="$(pwd)/roles"
export ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED="False"
ansible-playbook "$@" /dev/stdin <<END
---
- hosts: $HOST_PATTERN
  roles:
    - $ROLE
END
```

В соседнем [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145504/2795592) есть упоминание про [ansible-toolbox](https://github.com/larsks/ansible-toolbox) – там есть хелперы `ansible-role` и `ansible-task`.